# Wi-Fi speeds very slow on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, performance

I have a strange problem with my iPhone 5 running iOS 9.2.1. When I first join my home Wi-Fi network, it is running nice and fast. I use the Speed Test app and measure 60 Mbps down, 4 Mbps up, which is about my top speed with Charter.

However, after a few hours of using the phone on and off, the speed drops to roughly 1 Mbps down, 1-4 Mbps up. The kicker is that turning Wi-Fi off, then on resets it back to running at full speed.

The network is running on Ubiquiti's Uni-Fi AP-Pro. Other devices don't seem to be experiencing these types of issues. I already tried resetting network settings, then re-joining the Wi-Fi network. Also, turned off Wi-Fi assist.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? If so, has anyone found a fix?

Comment: what is the link speed the AP is reporting for that client? When the speed is fast vs. when it's slow would be ideal to document/measure.

Comment: Currently 74Mbps TX, 24 RX.

Comment: Odd - most WiFi has symmetrical link speed negotiation. For example, MCS 23 translates to 450 Mbps for me at the moment. I was seeing if you could blame the speed difference between the Mac and the base station (so noise, or radio effects) as opposed to problems outside your router.